# List of listings similar to list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, listings

After learning on the net I managed to get this type of list of figures :

[image]
And I want exactly the same with the list of listings, but here is what I get : 
[image]
My code is this one :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% For french
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

% For figures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\addto\captionsfrench{%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Liste des figures}% 
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Liste des tables}%
}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\textsc{Figure} }
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{~~--}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}

% Numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi
\@arabic\c@figure}
\@addtoreset{figure}{chapter}
\makeatother

% Listings
\usepackage{listings}
\addto\captionsfrench{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Liste des codes}%
}

%Refs
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Begining of the document
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A figure
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:draw}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Hello,label={hello}]
A code
\end{lstlisting}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 A figure
\caption{Other caption}
\label{fig:drawbis}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Good bye,label={bye}]
Another code
\end{lstlisting}

\backmatter

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

All I need to write is the analog of the code :

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\textsc{Figure} }
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{~~--}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}
```

but for the listings. Is there anyway to do it with `tocloft` ? If not how can it be done ?

Many thanks.

Comment: `tocloft` does not hook into `\lstlistoflistings`, unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `tocloft` can't hook into ToCs that are made by other packages, however, it's possible to use `\newlistof{...}` to redefine the `\lstoflistings` -- unfortunately, this requires knowledge of the counter being used for `listings` (its name is `lstlisting`) and `\newlistof`... tries to define a new counter for this -- this must fail (and is a design flaw of `tocloft`, in my point of view)

However, it's possible to `\let\c@lstlisting\relax`, after this `\newlistof` works.

Use the optional argument of `\newlistof` for the resetting counter to get correct hyperlinks.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% For french

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

% For figures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\addto\captionsfrench{%
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Liste des figures}% 
  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Liste des tables}%
}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\textsc{Figure} }
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{~~--}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}

% Numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi
\@arabic\c@figure}
\@addtoreset{figure}{chapter}
\makeatother

% Listings
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter

 \AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\c@lstlisting\relax
  \newlistof[chapter]{lstlisting}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
  \renewcommand{\cftlstlistingindent}{20pt}
  \renewcommand{\cftlstlistingfont}{\textsc{Listing} }
  \renewcommand{\cftlstlistingaftersnum}{~~--}
  \renewcommand{\cftlstlistingnumwidth}{3em}
  \renewcommand{\theHlstlisting}{listings.\thelstlisting}
}
\makeatother



\addto\captionsfrench{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Liste des codes}%
}

\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{%
  \listoflstlisting
}
%Refs
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Begining of the document

\begin{document}


\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings
\listoffigures

\mainmatter


\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A figure
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:draw}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Hello,label={hello}]
A code
\end{lstlisting}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 A figure
\caption{Other caption}
\label{fig:drawbis}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Good bye,label={bye}]
Another code
\end{lstlisting}

\backmatter

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The hyperanchors are not correct yet!

Comment: Also the items in the LOL are not spaced just as in LOF but it is fixed with : 
`\renewcommand{\cftlstlistingfont}{\vspace{.3cm}\textsc{Listing} }` instead of `\renewcommand{\cftlstlistingfont}{\textsc{Listing} }`

Comment: @JohnMarjan: Well, I leave that to you, the hyperlinks are working now with the update

Answer (score 3):

In case that `tocloft.sty` is not a must, I can offer a solution with `titletoc.sty`.  I think the interface is cleaner.  There is also a solution at the end how to get rid of the additional vertical space in LOF.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft,openany]{book}

% For french
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

% For figures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\addto\captionsfrench{%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Liste des figures}% 
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Liste des tables}%
}

% Listings
\usepackage{listings}
\addto\captionsfrench{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Liste des codes}%
}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}

\titlecontents{figure}
  [2.6cm]
  {}
  {\contentslabel[\textsc{Figure}~\thecontentslabel~--]{2.6cm}}
  {\hspace*{0em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{lstlisting}
  [2.65cm]
  {}
  {\contentslabel[\textsc{Listing}~\thecontentslabel~--]{2.65cm}}
  {\hspace*{0em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

%Refs
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Begining of the document
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  A figure
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:draw}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Hello,label={hello}]
A code
\end{lstlisting}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{A figure}
  \caption{Other caption}
  \label{fig:drawbis}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Good bye,label={bye}]
Another code
\end{lstlisting}

\backmatter

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \let\addvspace\@gobble
  \listoffigures
\endgroup

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Great answer. Good to now in case of option clashes :)