# Create List of Listings like List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I'm trying to make a List of Listings that appears in the Table of Contents like List of Figures. I'm using a class that was provided for me, and I tried editing it but it isn't working.

This is what the List of Figures looks like:
[image]

But this is what the attempted List of Listings looks like:
[image]

For some reason, it's being treated as if it is a Table of Contents.

Here is the code in the `.cls` file:

```
%
%   List of figures
%
\def\textofLoF#1{\gdef\@textofLoF{#1}}  \textofLoF{List of Figures}
\def\listoffigures{\chapter*{\@textofLoF\@mkboth{}{}}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\@textofLoF}
   \hbox to\textwidth{Figure Number \hfill Page}
   {\let\footnotemark\relax  % in case one is in the title
    \uwsinglespace
   \@starttoc{lof}
    }
   }
%
%   List of listings
%
\def\textofLoL#1{\gdef\@textofLoL{#1}}  \textofLoL{List of Listings}
\def\lstlistoflistings{\chapter*{\@textofLoL\@mkboth{}{}}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\@textofLoL}
   \hbox to\textwidth{Listing Number \hfill Page}
   {\let\footnotemark\relax  % in case one is in the title
    \uwsinglespace
   \@starttoc{lol}
    }
   }
%
```

I just copied the block for the List of Figures and tried changing it appropriately, but it doesn't work. I assume this is because `\lstlistoflistings` is in the `listings` package, so it's different, but I'm not sure in what way.

EDIT: here is a minimal `.tex` file that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass [11pt, proquest] {uwthesis}[2020/02/24]
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}  % Print the chapter and sections to the toc

% for code listings
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}


% ----- contents & etc.
%
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings

\textpages

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    test
    \caption{Pipeline Diagram}
    \label{fig:pipeline}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Example file snippet]
hello world
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey Liz. Can you also generate code that would resemble a minimal example to go with your code snippets? It should generate a ToC and LoF and LoL so we can see the layout it produces by default. From there we can move to providing solutions. Your minimal example should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: Is this question helpful? [List of listings similar to list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306858)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I did see that question, thank you! But I wasn't sure if the solution provided was what I wanted to go with, because what I want to do is edit the `.cls` file I was given to account for a List of Listings, as opposed to doing it in the preamble.

Comment: @Werner, I think I added what you were suggesting, but let me know if this is still not right. Thank you!

Comment: Alas, there are hundreds of different document classes named thesis.  Your MWE works fine for me, except that \textpages is undefined.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, oops I changed the class name to be general, but it didn't occur to me one might want to look at the actual existing class, but it's from [here](https://staff.washington.edu/fox/tex/uwthesis.shtml). It's very long and there might be other stuff in there causing the problem, but I'm not sure how to tackle that...

Comment: It is not recommended to edit class files. Package `listings` defines `\lstlistoflistings` too and therefore overwrites your definition. Maybe you want to use a different macro name like `\listoflistings`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467186/listings-tables-and-figures-in-one-table-of-contents Recommended link